# How to use a App.config file in WPF applications?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, configuration

I created an App.config file in my WPF application:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appsettings>
    <add key="xmlDataDirectory" value="c:\testdata"/>
  </appsettings>
</configuration>
```

Then I try to read the value out with this:

```cs
string xmlDataDirectory = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("xmlDataDirectory");
```

But it says this is obsolete and that I should use ConfigurationManager which I can't find, even searching in the class view.

Does anyone know how to use config files like this in WPF?

Comment: Is there an easy way to get settings out of ```appsettings.json``` file without having to new up IConfiguration? Because doesn't the Startup page do that for us already? Maybe inject into MainWindow code-behind?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You have to reference the `System.Configuration` assembly which is in GAC.

Use of `ConfigurationManager` is not WPF-specific: it is the privileged way to access configuration information for any type of application.

Please see [Microsoft Docs - `ConfigurationManager` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager) for further info.

Comment: yes that's it, I had to change the name from appsettings to appSettings, add the System.Configuration reference to my project, and then use this: string xmlDataDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("xmlDataDirectory");

Answer (score 35):

In my case, I followed the steps below.

App.config

```xml
<configuration>  
   <startup> 
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

 <appSettings>
   <add key="POCPublishSubscribeQueueName" value="FormatName:Direct=OS:localhost\Private$\POCPublishSubscribe"/>
 </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Added `System.Configuartion` to my project.

Added `using System.Configuration` statement in file at top.

Then used this statement:

```cs
string queuePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["POCPublishSubscribeQueueName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 18):

In your `app.config`, change your appsetting to:

```xml
<applicationSettings>
    <WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="appsetting" serializeAs="String">
            <value>c:\testdata.xml</value>
        </setting>
    </WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then, in the code-behind:

```cs
string xmlDataDirectory = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.appsetting.ToString()
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to reference `System.Configuration` via explorer (not only append `using System.Configuration`). Then you can write:

```
string xmlDataDirectory = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("xmlDataDirectory");
```

Tested with VS2010 (thanks to www.developpez.net).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, right-clicked on References and added System.Configuration from the Reference Manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the reference to `System.configuration` in your solution. Also, include `using System.Configuration;`. Once you do that, you'll have access to all the configuration settings.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good article about [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/application-settings-architecture?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) on Microsoft.
According to that you need to:

- manually create App.config file (from Project Context menu -> Add -> New Item... -> Application Configuration File.)
  [image: Dialog window for adding application config file]
- add required sections there (I'm using only application scope settings):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings"
                      type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="DevelopmentEnvironmentManager.WPF.Properties.Settings"
                     type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <DevelopmentEnvironmentManager.WPF.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="SqliteDbFilePath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Database.db</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="BackgroundColor" serializeAs="String">
                <value>White</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="TextColor" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Black</value>
            </setting>
        </DevelopmentEnvironmentManager.WPF.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

NOTE: Replace '*DevelopmentEnvironmentManager.WPF*' with the name of your application.

Additionally, you can go to Properies of the project and add Settings.Designer:
[image: Project settings]
this will add convenient designer to your project, so you don't have to edit XML manually:
[image: Location of the file in Solution exporer]
[image: Settings designer in action]

To access settings from the code - simply save and close all config editors, build app and access static Propeties (again, do not forget to change app name in the namespace):

```
string databasePath = DevelopmentEnvironmentManager.WPF.Properties.Settings.Default.SqliteDbFilePath;
```

[image: Accessing settings from code]

Answer (score 2):

This also works

```
WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default["appsetting"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change configuration file schema back to **`DotNetConfig.xsd`** via properties of the `app.config` file. To find destination of needed schema, you can search it by name or create a WinForms application, add to project the configuration file and in it's properties, you'll find full path to file.

Answer (score -2):

I have a Class Library WPF Project, and I Use:

```
'Read Settings
Dim value as string = My.Settings.my_key
value = "new value"

'Write Settings
My.Settings.my_key = value
My.Settings.Save()
```