# User contol for storing connectionstrings

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, connection-string

I have been searching all over the internet to find a good control to help store connectionstrings.
But couldn't find one.

What i'm looking for is something like the connectionstring manager in linqpad or visual studio.
Try looking at the control to the left in linqpad
http://www.linqpad.net/

So preferably it can do:
- add connectionstrings with a test option
- store connectionstrings
- in WPF

The best I have been able to find is this one
http://jake.ginnivan.net/wpf-sql-connection-user-control
But it is unmaintained...

In short
I'm looking for a control where users of my application can add connectionstrings at runtime, and use them for running scripts...

Do you know where i can find one?

**Edit**
This is what I'm looking for, but where can i find a control like that?

Comment: I think that writing your own is faster than looking for one on internet

Comment: @Thomas yes I fear you are right, but I'm still hoping...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WPF, but you can add a configuration file to store your connection string information.

See this thread:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/92296-how-to-add-webconfig-in-wpf/

And see this question:
[How to use a App.config file in WPF applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806174/how-to-use-a-app-config-file-in-wpf-applications)

Comment: Not close, I'm looking for a control where users of my application can add connectionstrings at runtime, and use them for running scripts...

Comment: Okay, but you didn't specify that in your question, so it's not really fair to downvote my answer. Under normal circumstances, using a configuration file would be the recommendation.

Comment: I did specify that in my question, the link is to functionality like that, and if you are familiar with linqpad or visual studio the connectionstring manager part should lead you in that direction.

Comment: I didn't think it was anything personal.

Comment: Is there an aspect of creating the control that's more complicated than I'm anticipating? Do you want a control where the user can enter a connection string, or do you want something more graphical where the user can see a list of servers, databases, etc. and build the connection string?

Comment: I want a control where the user can built up the connectionstring, and test it, and store it for later use.

Comment: Build up how though? Will they assembly it piece by piece, by entering in the server name, database name, etc.? Or will they just enter the whole connection string into a TextBox?