# WPF / C#: Is it considered bad practice to put resources in Application and casting Application.Current to access them?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a type MyApplication that derives from Application. The whole program has only 1 Application object running the entire time. If some shared resources such as strings, ints and some configuration values are placed in MyApplication, what do you think are acceptable ways to access them from other classes with no reference to the application object? Is it ok to access a public string in MyApplication by calling `((MyApplicationType)Application.Current).SomeString`? Or should I explicitly add a way to reference the Application object?

How about methods? Can I also access the application's method by calling `((MyApplicationType)Application.Current).SomeMethod()`? It definitely works but I'm not clear about the implications and whether this is considered bad practice.

Comment: Note that all resources in your application must be loaded together with your app. The larger the resources, the longer your app will take to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to remark of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current.aspx), I think it is OK to do that.
But I think defining resources in the ResourceDictionary is better way and you could use it in XAML / C#, and easier to do localisation.
You could refer to links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547.aspx

Remarks

Application is a per-AppDomain singleton type that implements the static Current property to provide shared access to the Application instance for the current AppDomain. This design guarantees that state managed by Application, including shared resources and state, is available from a single, shared location.
This property is thread safe and is available from any thread.

For the method, I think that depends on what your method does. 
If your method just returns temporary file path, why don't you make it static?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration values should be from read an app.config file. Here's an SO Q/A on that: 
[How to use a App.config file in WPF applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806174/how-to-use-a-app-config-file-in-wpf-applications)

For values that don't change or aren't configurable, use a static class with constant members to make them accessible as needed.

```
public static class UsefulConstants
{
  public const int FeetInMile = 5280;

  public const int DaysInWeek = 7;

  public const string SampleString = "This is a sample";
}
```

Using the static class is simple.

```
int f = UsefulConstants.FeetInMile;
```

Related integer values can be specified as an enum.

```
public enum MonthValue
{
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    //Omitted for brevity...
    December = 12
}
```

Using an enum has the added benefit of letting you restrict method parameters to relevant values.

```
public SomeFunction(MonthValue month)
{
   //Do something here with the month passed in
}
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I'm already using app.config and enums. Some of my app.config values are supposed to be integers, so i perform all the error checking and casting in the MyApplication object and stores all the setup values there to make it cleaner. Now my question is, is it acceptable to access values using `((MyApplicationType)Application.Current)`, i'm not optimizing speed or resource usage, just wanna know the proper way to access the Application object''s values