# How to change the content of my app.config after installation of the application

Tags: c#, configuration, installation, app-config

I am working on WPF application that soon has to be ready for installation but there is a functionallity that allows the user to make changes to the app.config file and I don't know how to do that from the code-behind of the application.Also I don't know how this is going to work after the installation of the app.

Simply said: I have a window that allows the user to enter a text that is going to be searched for in the web.config of another application.So in my app.config I have a different searches and I want after the installation the user to be able (after entering values in the window's textoxes) enter new values in the app.config of the application.

Can somebody tell if that is possible and eventually how I could achieve this?

Comment: If you don't want to provide a GUI then Notepad will work fine to edit the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a App.config file in WPF applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806174/how-to-use-a-app-config-file-in-wpf-applications)

Answer (score 2):

How I did in my application. I have app.config as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="StoreConnectionString"
          connectionString="Data Source=.\;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Initial Catalog=Store;Integrated Security=False;"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="ExportPath" value="D:\" />
        <add key="CompanyName" value="My Company" />
        <add key="mail" value="email@mail.com" />
        <add key="phone" value="+992918254040" />
        <add key="ExpDate" value="Pink" />
        <add key="Print" value="No" />
        <add key="EnforcePassw" value="Yes"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

So I can change and save app Settings from my application, here is code

```
private void btnSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //returns path of folder where your application is
            string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            //combines path of folder and file
            string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "MyApp.exe.config");
            //Defines the configuration file mapping for an .exe application
            ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;
            System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            config.AppSettings.Settings["ExportPath"].Value = txtExport.Text;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["CompanyName"].Value = txtComapny.Text;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["mail"].Value = txtEmail.Text;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["phone"].Value = txtPhone.Text;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["Print"].Value = print;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["EnforcePassw"].Value = password;
            config.AppSettings.Settings["ExpDate"].Value = color;
            config.Save(); 

        }
```

Hope it will be help you!

If you want to add new strings use this code;

```
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Key", "Value");
```

Comment: In your case you are setting values for already existing elements in the file.

I am trying to add entirely new element in the <apppSettings> section.
I already have it formatted as a XElement and I just need a method that allows me to Add to the child elements of the <appSettings>

Comment: See updated answer, use             config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("Key", "Value"); to add more strings;

Comment: Thank You for the answer!It seems to be working that way.
Can I ask you to give me a short explanation of what the first five rows of your method are doing?

Comment: Is there a way not to use the ExeConfigurationFileMap ?
I've been testing it for the last 10 minutes and it started to behave in a weird way.

Adds more than 1 element(when I am trying to add just a single one), formats it quiete wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful
[Configuring Application/User Settings in WPF the easy way.](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/06/17/configuring-applicationuser-settings-in-wpf-the-easy-way.aspx)