# Save Database Configuration Details in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an app whose first window is a database configuration window. From this window, a user inputs server details and selects the database they want to use  upon which the database connection details and carried over to the login window and the window is opened.

The login and subsequent windows use the database details for their sql connection string.

My question here is this: how can I save these connection details from the configuration window such that the user bypasses this screen if they have already established a previous connection? I have the idea to store these details to a file and set a boolean condition in App.xaml.cs, but I do not know how to go about doing it.

Here is my code:

For the Database Settings Window

DatabaseSettings.xaml.cs

```C#
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connectionString = "Data Source = " + txtServer.Text + "; User Id = " + txtUserID.Text + "; Password = " + txtPassword.Password + "";
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string message = "Connection Successful Please Select a Database to Proceed";
            string caption = "Success!";
            MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.OK;
            MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Information;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon);
            txtServer.IsEnabled = false;
            txtUserID.IsEnabled = false;
            txtPassword.IsEnabled = false;
            btnTest.IsEnabled = false;
            cmbdatabase.IsEnabled = true;
            btnConfigure.IsEnabled = true;
            btnConfigure.IsDefault = true;

            sql = "EXEC sp_databases";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            cmbdatabase.Items.Clear();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cmbdatabase.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    static string Encrypt_Password(string value)
    {
        using (SHA256Managed sha2 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            UTF8Encoding uTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] data = sha2.ComputeHash(uTF8.GetBytes(value));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
        }
    }



private void btnConfigure_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                string selected = cmbdatabase.Text;
                txtSelectedDBItem.Text = cmbdatabase.Text;
                string EncryptedPassword = Encrypt_Password(txtPassword.Password);
                connectionString = "Data Source = " + txtServer.Text + "; Initial Catalog = " + selected + "; User Id = " + txtUserID.Text + "; Password = " + txtPassword.Password + "";
                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                sql = "INSERT INTO Proc_Activity_Log ([UserName], [Password], [AccessTime], [MachineSerial]) values(@userId, @password, @accessTime, @machineserial)";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", txtUserID.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", EncryptedPassword);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessTime", dateTime.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineserial", txtMachineSerialNo.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }

                UserInterface.frmLogin loginScreen = new UserInterface.frmLogin(txtUserID.Text, txtPassword.Password, txtServer.Text, txtSelectedDBItem.Text);
                spashScreen.Show();
                this.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error Here:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

For the login screen

frmLogin.xaml.cs

```C#
public frmLogin(string uname, string pwd, string server, string db)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            txtServerUser.Text = uname;
            txtServerPwd.Password = pwd;
            txtServer.Text = server;
            txtSelectedDBItem.Text = db;
        }

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + txtServer.Text + "; Initial Catalog=" + txtSelectedDBItem.Text + "; Integrated Security=True;");

            try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();
                String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.users WHERE name=@Username and password=@Password";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtLogin.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPwd.Password);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    frmMDI yourDesktop = new frmMDI(txtLogin.Text, txtServerUser.Text, txtServerPwd.Password, txtServer.Text, txtSelectedDBItem.Text);
                    yourDesktop.Show();
                    this.Close();


                }
                else
                {
                    txtLogin.Text = "admin";
                    txtPwd.Password = "admin";
                    txtLogin.Focus();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = "The Following Error Occurred: " + ex.Message;
                string caption = "Invalid Action";
                MessageBoxButton buttons = MessageBoxButton.OK;
                MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.Error;
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons, icon);
            }

            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

From the screenshots I have included below one can infer which buttons represent the click events in the code above

Database Settings Window - Testing Connection

[Database Settings Window - Testing Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyM3A.png)

Database Settings Window - Configuring Database

[Database Settings Window - Configuring Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0EaJ.png)

And finally the login window

[login window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMbU9.png)

Comment: Simple way is to introduce an app.config file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806174/how-to-use-a-app-config-file-in-wpf-applications and you can store settings on success or clicking a button

Comment: If your app is installed then your users often won't be able to write to config files unless you have them in appdata rather than program files. Or you're still using win xp.  Personally, I'd probably build a class representing the connection properties and serialise + encrypt this to appdata Roaming.

Comment: @Andy great suggestion