# Use previously entered value in a TextBox in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, desktop-application

I am creating a WPF app in which i want the following functionality.
I have a textbox in which the user would enter value on app launch. Afterwords the **same value** is present in the textbox every time when the app is relaunched.
How to achieve this?

Comment: You need a config file which is read whenever your program launches. 

[Similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806174/how-to-use-a-app-config-file-in-wpf-applications)

[ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. Open the settings.settings-File under Properties in your Project and add an entry to the list. Set the Scope to user (or application if only one usere is on the current computer). In your Code you cann access this setting with `Settings.Default.MySavedString`
2. Write a custom serializer for it. For example with an xml-file. Therefor you can user `XDocument.Load` to load the data from your xml-File. And `XDocument.Save` to write the xml-file.